# SQL Case Basics

Tags: sql

I'm just new in this SQL world I just wonder if you have this logic

**If NAME is JOHN and if ID is JOHN A then JOHN 2**

**If ID is JOHN A then JOHN 1**

I'm Trying to figure out if the SQL code to make this work is

*Case
When "ID" is 'JOHN A' then 'JOHN B'*

*When "ID" is 'JOHN A' then 'JOHN 2" when "NAME" is 'JOHN'
End*

Is any of those correct?
Any better SQL in Case basis?
Help would be very much appreciated

Comment: which RDBMS? sql server? or any other products? I am not very sure in the others, but seems you need to use `=` then `is` in sql server

Comment: `Case When ID = 'John A' And Name <> 'John' Then 'John 1' When ID = 'John A' And Name = 'John' Then 'John 2' End`

Comment: Will this also work?

Case
When "ID" = 'JOHN A' and "NAME" = 'JOHN' then 'JOHN 2' 
When "ID" = 'JOHN A' then 'JOHN 1'
End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test using Sql Server on rextester: http://rextester.com/GLP50097

```
create table t (id varchar(32), name varchar(32))
insert into t values 
 ('John A','Steve')
,('John A','John')
,('Joan A','Joan')
```

query:

```
select 
    id
  , name
  , case 
      when name = 'John' 
         and id = 'John A' 
        then 'John 2'
      else name
      end as expr
from t
```

returns:

```
+--------+-------+--------+
|   id   | name  |  expr  |
+--------+-------+--------+
| John A | Steve | Steve  |
| John A | John  | John 2 |
| Joan A | Joan  | Joan   |
+--------+-------+--------+
```